# External library specific COMPILE_DEFINITIONS in cmake

Tags: cmake

I've written a cmake module for finding QCustomPlot. However, to use the shared library, one needs to #define QCUSTOMPLOT_USE_LIBRARY. I'd like to provide this define through cmake, automatically adding the definition to any project that uses QCustomPlot.

Here is a snippet of my cmake module and my current attempted solution:

```
SET(QCP_FOUND "NO")
IF(QCP_LIBRARY AND QCP_INCLUDE_DIR)
  SET(QCP_FOUND "YES")
  SET_PROPERTY(
    GLOBAL
    APPEND
    PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS QCUSTOMPLOT_USE_LIBRARY
    )
ENDIF(QCP_LIBRARY AND QCP_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

However, no linkers append the -DQCUSTOMPLOT_USE_LIBRARY flag in my compilations. What's the right way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There is no global property `COMPILE_DEFINITIONS`. But there are such properties for  directory, target and source file (see [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-properties.7.html)). So probably the closest commands for you are:

```
set(QCP_FOUND "NO")
if(QCP_LIBRARY AND QCP_INCLUDE_DIR)
  set(QCP_FOUND "YES")
  set_directory_properties(
      PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS QCUSTOMPLOT_USE_LIBRARY
  )
endif()
```

But I think that this kind of job is for imported targets:

```
add_library(QCP::qcp UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(
    QCP::qcp
    PROPERTIES
    IMPORTED_LOCATION "${QCP_LIBRARY}"
    INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${QCP_INCLUDE_DIR}"
    INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS QCUSTOMPLOT_USE_LIBRARY
)
```

and usage:

```
add_executable(foo ...)
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC QCP::qcp)
```

Comment: See also: http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_compile_definitions.html -- http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#build-specification-and-usage-requirements -- http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-packages.7.html#creating-packages